# Blazor component JS isolation not finding js reference

Tags: javascript, blazor, web-component

I created a Razor component library with the intent of housing some custom Blazor components.

One in particular is a wrapper over the Infragistics Dock Manager Web Component.

Within the component library project I created a folder under the wwwroot folder named dockmanager and added my javascript wrapper file dockmanger.js to it.

There are a number of JS module export functions that I've included within the dockmanager.js file  to support my Dock Manager Blazor wrapper component.

Within the Dock Manager Blazor component OnAfterRenderAsync method I attempt to acquire an IJSObjectReference following this code ..

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        try
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                // add reference to dockmanager.js module
                _module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./dockmanager/dockmanager.js");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    
    }
```

In a separate Blazor test project I reference my Razor component library and add the Dock Manager Blazor component to a test page.

When I navigate to the test page containing a reference to my custom component, at startup, I get an exception in the custom component OnAfterRenderAsync when I attempt to acquire the IJSObjectReference.

The exception is as follows:

> Failed to fetch dynamically imported module:
> http://localhost:12203/dockmanager/dockmanager.js TypeError: Failed to
> fetch dynamically imported module:
> http://localhost:12203/dockmanager/dockmanager.js

I have triple checked the paths and they seem correct.

All Isolated JS examples are within a Blazor project however in my case I created the custom component within a Blazor component library and am referencing within a Blazor test project.

Should the path to the JS file be different?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to alter the path as follows:

```
_module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/NextWare.UI.Components/dockmanager/dockmanager.js");
```

Where the NextWare.UI.Components refers to the name of the Blazor component library.

I hope this helps others!